# Why use immer for a reducer instead of just spread operator?

Tags: javascript, immer.js

What is the benefit of using immer for a reducer? Some code I've seen looks like:

```
const reducer = (state, {field, newValue}) => {
  return produce(state, (draft) => {
    // logic to mutate draft
  }
}
```

How does this differ from the below, which doesn't need a 3rd party lib?

```
const reducer = (state, {field, newValue}) => {
  const draft = {...state}
  // logic to mutate draft
}
```

Comment: I saw that question already, and no I don't think so - it talks about immutable.js, which is different from immer.

Comment: The reasons are pretty much the same though: Yes, you can use spread syntax to keep your state immutable. The libraries (immutable in that question, immer in yours) are trying to make it easier to do, and harder to mess up. Whether that's worth it is debatable, but that's the benefit they're aiming for.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is where the value is - with immer or spread I assume I can still mess up by doing `state.name = 'bob'`, and if I can do the same thing with a spread operator and fewer lines of code and no external lib, isn't that the objectively better way?

Comment: `with immer or spread I assume I can still mess up by doing state.name = 'bob'` That will mess it up if you're doing normal code, but not with immer. Inside that function starting with `(draft) =>` you can write `draft.name = 'bob'`, and immer will do the work to apply that change *without* mutation. So again, the point is to make it easier to do and harder to mess up. Yes, you have to call the `produce` function, but then you can use all the mutation-happy code you like inside it.

Comment: Also, i want to point out that the example in your question has the simplest case: a single top-level copy. That simplicity is a great way to ask the question, but in the real world you often have to do nested updates. With spread syntax, you need to remember to copy at each level of the object, which opens up more opportunities to accidentally mutate. `immer` automatically works with nested updates, copying exactly as much as is needed, and no more.